# How do you add leading spacing to text?

Tags: ios, fonts, nsattributedstring, uifont

I've got some requirements that text within an app must conform to company branding stipulations.
In particular the text must have tracking and leading values added to it.
Tracking doesn't exist in iOS but I found something on line for converting font tracking values to font spacing values.

However I can't find anything about adding leading to text. Here's a quote from the requirements:

".. for larger sizing (above 18pt), we also plug a +2 value of the type's point size into the leading". And there's also a table of fonts sizes used within the app and associated values to be used for the leading (30, 26, 20, 18, 12).

How do I apply these leading values to the text? I've tried searching for this but can't find very much at all.

I saw [here](http://kalyanchakravarthy.net/blog/using-nsattributedstring-on-ios.html) which says

> "NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading - font leading basically means line
>   spacing. This flag indicates the call to make use of default line
>   spacing specified by the font."

It says leading and spacing are the same, but this has confused me - implying that the only way to change the leading is to set the spacing, yet that conflicts with the requirements where the spacing is the same but the leading changes depending on the font point size.

Comment: What about `NSKernAttributeName` or [this (found in 10s with google)](http://www.devsign.co/notes/tracking-and-character-spacing)?

Comment: @meaning-matters  If kerning is the same as leading then it sounds promising. I'm a novice regarding fonts hence was unaware that kerning is the search term that could be used to google, I was using leading as a search term.

Comment: No worries, I had to look it up too ;-) Typography is bloody interesting isn't it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd like to suggest you create an `NSAttributedString` subclass or category that has an added `NSString` property and a font size property (or an `enum` if you wish to name the various fonts, for example HeaderFont, ... which then defines size and possibly other attributes).

In the 'set' method of that `NSString` property you then put the code to setup the various attributes.

This way you hide all these nasty details, keeping them in one central place, and end up with a very simple class.

Could look something like:

```
UILabel* someLabel;

someLabel.attributedText = [[MyAttributedString alloc] initWithText:"Hello" font:HeaderFont];
```

Good luck!